# Reparametrization of an EBM in the latent space

Tags: probability, distributions, latent-variable

In [[Xiao et al., 2020]](https://invertibleworkshop.github.io/INNF_2020/accepted_papers/pdfs/4.pdf), the authors propose a reparametrization of their exponentially-tilted generative model from the data space to the latent space. The model is defined as:

\begin{equation}
    h_{\phi, \theta}(x) = \frac{1}{Z_{\phi, \theta}} \int p_{\phi}(x, z)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)} dz = \frac{p_{\phi}(x)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}}{Z_{\phi, \theta}}
\end{equation}

where $Z_{\phi, \theta} = \int p_{\phi}(x) e^{-E_{\theta}(x)} dx$ is a normalizing constant, and $p_{\phi}(x)$ is a probabilisitc generative model (e.g. VAE).

$p_{\phi}(x)$ has a decoder component $G_{\phi}$ s.t.:

\begin{equation}
    z \sim p(z), \; \; x = G_{\phi}(z)
\end{equation}

where $z$ is a latent variable with a simple prior distribution $p(z)$.

Then the authors propose to reparametrize the EBM using latent variable $z$ as shown below:

\begin{equation}
    p_{\phi, \theta}(z) = \frac{p(z)e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}}{Z_{\phi, \theta}}
\end{equation}

Here is my attempt at deriving the reparametrization:

\begin{align}
    h_{\phi, \theta}(x) &= \frac{p_{\phi}(x)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}}{\int p_{\phi}(x)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)} dx} \\\\
    &= \frac{p_{\phi}(G_{\phi}(z))e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}}{\int p_{\phi}(G_{\phi}(z))\det{\begin{vmatrix}\frac{dG_{\phi}(z)}{dz} \end{vmatrix}}e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))} dz} \\\\
    &= \frac{p_{\phi}(G_{\phi}(z))e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}}{\int p(z)e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}dz} \\\\
    &= \frac{p_{\phi}(G_{\phi}(z))e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}}{Z_{\phi, \theta}}
\end{align}

Moving from the first to the second line uses the theorem of change of variable in a multivariate integral:

\begin{equation}
\int p_{\phi}(x)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}dx = \int p_{\phi}(G_{\phi}(z)) \det{\begin{vmatrix}\frac{dG_{\phi}(z)}{dz}\end{vmatrix}} e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))} dz
\end{equation}

Moving from the second to the third line requires the theorem of change of variables in a density function:

\begin{equation}
    p(z) = p_{\phi}(G_{\phi}(z)) \det{\begin{vmatrix}\frac{dG_{\phi}(z)}{dz}\end{vmatrix}}
\end{equation}

I have two questions here:

**1. How do I move from $h_{\phi, \theta}(x) = \frac{p_{\phi}(G_{\phi}(z))e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}}{Z_{\phi, \theta}}$ to $h_{\phi, \theta}(x) = \frac{p(z))e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}}{Z_{\phi, \theta}}$?**

**2. The change of variable theorems (both for multivariate integrals and density functions) require $G_{\phi}$ to be an invertible transformation from $Z$ to $X$ (domains of $z$ and $x$ respectively). This is not guaranteed for any generic probabilistic model, which is what the paper proposes for $p_{\phi}(x)$. Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar reparametrization in [[Nijkamp et al., 2022]](https://openreview.net/forum?id=4C93Qvn-tz), with a bit more context for the conditions of the transformation. It answers most of my questions, but I could still use some help to clarify a few points.

[[Nijkamp et al., 2022]](https://openreview.net/forum?id=4C93Qvn-tz) use a (volume preserving) normalizing flow specifically as a generative model. This leads to the following equation
(recall the definitions: $z \sim p(z)$, $x = G_{\phi}(z)$):

\begin{equation}
p(z) dz = p_{\phi}(x) dx
\end{equation}

And similarly for the new EBM model:

\begin{equation}
p_{\phi, \theta}(z) dz = p_{\phi, \theta}(x) dx
\end{equation}

From here, we can derive the reparametrization as:

\begin{align}
p_{\phi, \theta}(z) dz &= \frac{e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}p_{\phi}(x)dx}{Z_{\phi, \theta}} \\
p_{\phi, \theta}(z) dz &= \frac{e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}p(z)dz}{Z_{\phi, \theta}} \\
\end{align}

$dz$ cancels out from both sides and we get:

\begin{equation}
p_{\phi, \theta}(z) = \frac{e^{-E_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z))}p(z)}{Z_{\phi, \theta}}
\end{equation}

Note that this only holds if $G_{\phi}$ is a volume-preserving transformation. I still don't know how [[Xiao et al., 2020]](https://invertibleworkshop.github.io/INNF_2020/accepted_papers/pdfs/4.pdf) use any generative model (e.g. VAE) to perform the same transformation.